# delete all last string of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

**Here is a column of my dataframe.**

[image]

I want to select for example for the first image 28g and delete (1 ONZ). **how can I do ?**

Comment: Learn how to ask questions. Don't provide images for data.

Comment: It is always recommended to post your samples in text format NOT in image formats, kindly edit your post by posting sample input and expected output sample in code tags.

Comment: Based on your comments to the answers, you want `28`, not `28g`. Please update the question accordingly. it is misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `replace`:

```
df.serving_size.str.replace('\(.*','')

0     NaN
1    28g 
2    28g 
3    28g
4    35g
5    52g
Name: serving_size, dtype: object
```

Comment: tell me you know how I can do to remove the "g" from the "28 g"?

Comment: Here `df.serving_size.str.replace('g \(.*','')`

Answer (score 1):

You can extract everything outside of the parentheses:

```
# original df
>>> df
      serving_size
0              NaN
1     28 g (1 ONZ)
2  28 g (0.25 cup)

>>> df.serving_size.str.extract('(.*)\(.*\)')
0      NaN
1    28 g 
2    28 g 
Name: serving_size, dtype: object
```

Comment: @ sacul thank you. but tell me you know how I can do to remove the "g" from the "28 g"?

Answer (score 1):

Using `split`

```
df.serving_size.str.split('(').str[0]
0    NaN
1    28g
2    28g
Name: serving_size, dtype: object
```

Comment: @ W-B thank you, but tell me you know how I can do to remove the "g" from the "28 g"?

Comment: @G.M df.serving_size.str.split(' ').str[0]